# Align content inside two side by side divs

Tags: css, less

I have two divs which are side by side and i need to top align the buttons at the bottom

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div><span>Heading</span></div>
    <div><button>Input</button><button>Input</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div><span>Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2</span></div>
    <div><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button></div>
  </div>
</div>

.outer {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

button {
  width: 80px;
}
```

This is the html structure https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPmeKd

This is the alignment that i want to achieve https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYWKRZ

I used bottom padding in the second code pen, but this isn't a viable solution because the number of rows for the heading and the buttons can vary and I would need to use jquery.

The question is if i can achieve this only through CSS. Changing the HTML structure, or using jquery at this moment would be a nightmare, I want to make sure that I can't achieve this through CSS alone at this point.

Comment: get height of other div and set it like `var height = document.getElementById('seconddiv').clientHeight;`
`document.getElementById('firstdiv').setAttribute("style",height);`

Comment: @Liviu Boboia at the moment your layout strategy is flexbox based. You basically have two columns (one for each div.container), but the problem you want to solve implies align items which are in different columns. Probably the best tool to achive this is using [grid layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).

Comment: @Liviu Boboia flexblx is best suited for one dimensional problems (such as align and space items inside a single row or a single column). If you have a two dimensional problem (you want to align items in different columns or rows) the way to go is using grid layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution using grid layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sample grid layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div><span>Heading</span></div>
        <div><span>Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2</span></div>
        <div><button>Input</button><button>Input</button></div>
        <div><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button></div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the CSS:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(200px, 200px));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
    grid-gap: 0.5em;
}
```

Notice that here the HTML structure has been flattened: you just need an outer grid container and then you put flatten grid items inside of it

Answer (score 0):

I am quite not sure as to what you're really asking for, but from my interpretation from the question above, I think it would be safe to add a `min-height` to your div, instead of a `padding-bottom`. 
This way you can keep adding buttons to the div.

Although to attain a responsive structure I would suggest you to read up about the CSS grid system. [More can be found here.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Comment: I can't use min-height, because the height of the button container will be larger than it needs to be if both containers will have only one row of buttons

Answer (score 0):

use this script

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div><span>Heading</span></div>
// add id leftside
    <div id="leftside"><button>Input</button><button>Input</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div><span>Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2</span></div>
// add id rightside
    <div id="rightside"><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button></div>
  </div>
</div>

.outer {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

button {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```
var height = document.getElementById('rightside').clientHeight;

document.getElementById('leftside').setAttribute("style","height:"+height+"px");
```

this is only for that scenario you post on code pen

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/rai-talha-rehman-khan/pen/BbwPNO)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div><span>Heading</span></div> 
      <div><button>Input</button><button>Input</button></div>        
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div><span>Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2Heading 2 ff s sfsd fsd</span></div>
    <div><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button><button>Input 2</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe this could help you:

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(1) { 
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

link on [codepen](https://codepen.io/trenccan777/pen/eXGjyZ).